# ¿Como obtener el valor de entrada de cada campo dinamico?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

***Dentro de mi formulario poseo una tabla que me permite agregar tantos campos dinámicos como desee.***

[image: tabla dinamica]

**Esta tabla permite registrar las herramientas que son utilizadas para la fabricación de una pieza.** Entonces la relación entre Pieza y Herramienta es una relación de muchos a muchos. **Básicamente porque una pieza puede tener de una a varias herramientas, y una misma herramienta puede estar en una a varias piezas.**

**Como pueden observar, en la imagen estoy recuperando la informacion correspondiente a cada campo dinamico, pero a su ves estos valores corresponden a una sola fila de la tabla**

y para esta **pieza EJE tengo 2 filas dinamicas**, es decir hay una herramienta mas que no se esta visualizando, entonces **¿como hago para mostrar todas las filas dinamicas que existan por cada pieza?.**

haciendo un

> $piezas  = Piece::with(['tools.insert'])->get();
>      dd($piezas);

obtengo lo siguiente para pieza id=6, puedo observar que en el atributo relations: existe una relacion con tools y este contiene una collection

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
        "tools" => Collection {#1238 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => Tool {#1114 ▶}
            1 => Tool {#1115 ▶}
          ]
        }
```

por ejemplo en

> 0 => Tool {#1114 ▶} 
>   existe lo sigueinte:

```
 #relations: array:2 [▼
                "pivot" => Pivot {#1157 ▶}
                "insert" => Insert {#1224 ▶}
              ]
```

**lo que quiero decir es que estoy obteniendo la informacion de manera correcta, pero no la puedo mostrar dinamicamente en mi tabla**, se puede observar que para esta pieza en particular existen 2 registros (2 filas para mostrar )  y solo puedo mostrar el primer registro
¿De que manera puedo resolver esto?

Controlador Piece: (metodo edit)

```
 public function edit($id)
    {       
        $piece = Piece::findOrFail($id);  

        return view('admin.pieces.partials.form', [                     
            'piezas'        => Piece::with(['tools.insert'])->get(),               
            'part_piece'    => Piece::pluck('part_piece', 'part_piece'), 
            'denomination'  => Piece::pluck('denomination', 'denomination'), 

            'type_gag'      => Gag::pluck('type_gag', 'type_gag'),           
            'category_gag'  => Gag::pluck('category_gag', 'category_gag'), 

            'part_program'  => Program::pluck('part_program', 'part_program'),                      
            'piece'         => $piece
        ]);       
    }
```

Este es mi formulario: (parte de mi formulario - tabla dinámica) De esta manera recorro mi foreach

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Herramientas</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">  
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">Posición</th>
                        <th width="20%">Herramienta</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Inserto</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Calidad</th>                 
                        <th width="5%">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    @if ($piece->exists)
                        @foreach ($piezas as $pieza)
                            @foreach ($pieza->tools as $tool)   
                                @if(old('position[]', $piece->id) == $tool->id)                                                                              
                                    <td><input type="text" name="position[]" value="{{ $tool->position }}" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>  
                                @endif  
                            @endforeach 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endif 
                    @if ($piece->exists)
                        @foreach ($piezas as $pieza)
                            @foreach ($pieza->tools as $tool)   
                                @if(old('code_tool[]', $piece->id) == $tool->id)                           
                                    <td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]"  value="{{ $tool->code_tool }}" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td> 
                                @endif  
                            @endforeach 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endif 
                    @if ($piece->exists)
                        @foreach ($piezas as $pieza)
                            @foreach ($pieza->tools as $tool)                            
                                @if(old('code_insert[]', $piece->id) == $tool->id)     
                                    <td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['code_insert'] }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td> 
                                @endif                               
                            @endforeach 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endif 
                    @if ($piece->exists)
                        @foreach ($piezas as $pieza)
                            @foreach ($pieza->tools as $tool)                            
                                @if(old('quality[]', $piece->id) == $tool->id)  
                                    <td><input type="text" name="quality[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['quality'] }}"placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      
                                    @endif                               
                            @endforeach 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endif 
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>  

                    </tr>  
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es mi script para agregar tampos dinamicos a mi tabla.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;

    $("#add").click(function(){

        ++i;

        $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="position[]" placeholder="Posición" class="form-control"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="quality[]" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td></tr>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });  

</script>
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

Con estos cambios he obtenido todas las herramientas registradas, pero en este caso necesito obtener las herramientas que están relacionadas con la pieza EJE id=6, 
**¿como obtengo las herramientas registradas que pertenecen a esta pieza?**

Formulario:

[image: tabla dinamica]

Tabla:

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Herramientas</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">  
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">Posición</th>
                        <th width="20%">Herramienta</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Inserto</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Calidad</th>                 
                        <th width="5%">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        @foreach ($piezas as $pieza)
                            @forelse ($pieza->tools as $tool)                               
                                <td><input type="text" name="position[]" value="{{ $tool->position }}" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>                             
                                <td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]"  value="{{ $tool->code_tool }}" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td>      
                                <td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['code_insert'] }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>  
                                <td><input type="text" name="quality[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['quality'] }}"placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      

                            @if ($loop->last)
                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>
                            @endif

                            @empty
                                <td colspan="4"></td>
                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>
                            @endforelse 
                            <li class="list-group-item">No hay piezas</li>
                        @endforeach  

                    </tr>  
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿con qué fin utilizas `old('position[]', $piece->id)`?

Comment: @Shaz bueno quisas lo estoy mal interpretando, con ```old(position[])``` obtengo la entrada antigua, el dato ingresado anteriormente, y con ```$piece->id``` es como preguntar si estoy hablado de la misma pieza por eso esta comparacion: ```old('position[]', $piece->id) == $tool->id) ```

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero ¿con qué fin lo haces?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo haría normalmente en estos casos, es simplemente iterar una sola vez por cada pieza y/o herramienta, depende lo que busque, y mostrar el botón de agregar nueva fila solo al final:

```
    @forelse ($piezas as $pieza)

      @forelse ($pieza->tools as $tool)   

        <td><input type="text" name="position[]" value="{{ $tool->position }}" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>                             
        <td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]"  value="{{ $tool->code_tool }}" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td>      
        <td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['code_insert'] }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>  
        <td><input type="text" name="quality[]"  value="{{ $tool->insert['quality'] }}"placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      


        @if ($loop->last)
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>
        @endif


      @empty

        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>

      @endforelse 

      No hay piezas

    @endforelse
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo rápido para darte una idea de cómo puedes resolverlo utilizando forelse, en caso que estén vacías alguna de las colecciones.

Como siempre, revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops

Comment: gracias por tu ejemplo voy trabajar sobre el, seguramemte cambiara el diseño y la forma de mi tabla dinamica, no comprendo cuando dices: (mostrar el boton de agregar nueva fila solo al final ) seguramente tambien cambiara mi script, podrias aclarame ese punto? Gracias

Comment: Si tienes 10 filas en la tabla de herramientas, ¿en cuál fila aparece el botón de agregar nuevas filas?, tú mismo tienes la respuesta.

Comment: estoy siguiendo tu ejemplo, puedes ver mi actualización? con las modificaciones que me indicaste presenta algunos errores que estoy tratando de corregirlos, básicamente me trae todas las herramientas registradas, y me repite no hay piezas, como corrigo esos puntos?, creo que debo indicarle el id de la pieza que quiero editar. Es por eso que volvemos a esto ```old('position[]', $piece->id)```, te invito a que observes mi actualización

Comment: '''$piezas = Piece::with(['tools.insert'])->get();''' con esto tengo todo lo que necesito. En mi actualizacion no puedo volcar los datos de esa pieza en particular en su lugar me esta trayendo todo, alguien podria ayudarme?